# Object oriented design patterns for error checking

Tags: error-handling, io, rust

I have written the following function that reads the contents of a text file and `panic!`s if an error is encountered.

```
fn get_file_contents(name: String) -> Result<String, io::Error> {
    let mut f = try!(File::open(name));
    let mut contents = String::new();
    try!(f.read_to_string(&mut contents));
    Ok(contents)
}
```

And the contents are extracted from the `Result` using:

```
let file_contents = match get_file_contents(file_name) {
    Ok(contents) => contents,
    Err(err) => panic!("{}", err)
};
```

I am now trying to reimplement this in an object oriented manner using structures and implementations. I created the following structure:

```
struct FileReader {
    file_name: String,
    file_contents: String,
}
```

and implemented the following methods:

```
impl FileReader {
    fn new(fname: &str) -> FileReader {
        FileReader {
            file_name: fname.to_string(),
            file_contents: String::new(),
        }
    }

    fn get_file_contents(&mut self) {
        let mut f = match File::open(&self.file_name) {
            Ok(file) => file,
            Err(err) => panic!("{}", err)
        };

        match f.read_to_string(&mut self.file_contents) {
            Ok(size) => size,
            Err(err) => panic!("{}", err)
        };
    }
}
```

In the OO approach, I haven't used the `try!` macro as I don't want the method to return any value. Is my OO implementation of `get_file_contents` a typical way of achieving this functionality? If not, can you please suggest an alternative way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the OO approach, I haven't used the `try!` macro as I don't want the method to return any value.

It's unclear why you think that "object oriented" means "doesn't return a value". If an error can occur, the code should indicate that.

Many languages have the equivalent of *exceptions* — out of band values that are thrown (also known as "returned") from a function or method. Note that this means that these languages allow for two disjoint types to be returned from a given function: the "normal" type and the "exceptional" type. That is a close equivalent for Rust's `Result`: `Result<NormalType, ExceptionalType>`.

Exceptional isn't a great term for this, as you should *expect* that opening a file should fail. There's an infinite number of ways that it could not work, but only a narrow subset of ways that it can succeed.

Panicking is closer to "kill the entire program / thread **right now**". Unlike C, you are forced to either deal with a problem, pass it back to the caller, or kill the program (panic).

If you would have thrown an exception in a language that supports them, use a `Result`. If you would have killed the program, or don't want to handle an error, use a panic.

---

If you want to panic in your particular case, use `unwrap`, or even better, `expect`:

```
fn get_file_contents(&mut self) {
    let mut f = File::open(&self.file_name).expect("Couldn't open file");
    f.read_to_string(&mut self.file_contents).expect("Couldn't read file");
}
```

---

> seems kind of clunky to have to deal with the `Result` for each method.

Which is why the [Error Handling section of *The Rust Programming Language*](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/error-handling.html) spends a good amount of time discussing the `try!` macro:

> A cornerstone of error handling in Rust is the `try!` macro. The `try!` macro abstracts case analysis like combinators, but unlike combinators, it also abstracts control flow. Namely, it can abstract the early return pattern seen above.

(this makes more sense in context of the page)

> I don't want my code to try and recover from the error (most likely caused by the file not being found) - I want it to print a useful error message and then die

Then by all means, panic. There's more succinct AND more detailed ways to do it (as shown above).

Comment: Thanks for your response. To clarify, I realise that OO methods can return values. The reason I didn't want to return a value is that is seems kind of clunky to have to deal with the `Result` for each method. In this simple case, I don't want my code to try and recover from the error (most likely caused by the file not being found) - I want it to print a useful error message and then die.

Comment: Another way of thinking about it is that I am trying to achieve something similar to Java's `Runtime Exception`. I.e. I am aware that an error can occur but if it does, it is irrecoverable so the best thing to do is kill the program and produce a useful error message.

Comment: Ah, `expect()` is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks very much for your help.